# Help me understand how to take derivative of the PDF of X~binom(n,p) with respect to p.

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, summation

This is the solution I was given. [image]

My questions:

1. Why is it summed from k=1 to x. Shouldn't it be from k=1 to n? (If not, why not?)
2. What is happening to the first term from line 1 to line 2? When we go from (n choose k) to (n choose k-1) why do we replace (k) by (n-k+1) in the product?
3. What is happening to the first term from line 2 to line 3? When we go from sum (from k=1 to x), to (k=0 to x-1), how does it change the test of the term? It seems like 1 was added to k in some places, but not in others.
4. Is this the easiest way to do this? I would never have thought to manipulate the sums like that without having seen the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Your $h(p)$ is what is commonly called the _cumulative probability distribution function_ of the random variable, and the commonly used acronym is CDF or cdf, not PDF (nor pdf). Be that as it may, surely you remember the product rule $$d(uv) = u(dv)+v(du)$$ from calculus and can apply it to $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$?. The reason that the sum is up to $x$ only, not $n$, is that $h(p)$ is _defined_ to be a sum that extends up to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In $h(p)$ it is defined as a sum that runs from 0 to x.
2. $k{n \choose k } = k\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)! (n-k)!} = (n-(k-1))\frac{n!}{(k-1)! (n-(k-1))!} = (n-k+1){n \choose k-1}$
3. Note $(n-k+1) = (n-(k-1))$, as k runs from 1 to n in the sum, k-1 runs from 0 to n-1. So we can replace the (k-1) term by k and change the range our summand runs through.
4. I'm not too sure if there is an easier method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on 3)? If we are simply replacing (k-1) by k, then why does $(1-p)^{n-k}$ change to $(1-p)^{n-k-1}$ instead of $(1-p)^{n-k+1}$, also (n-k+1) changes to (n-k) instead of (n-k+2)

Comment: In line 2 we consider $k=1$ then we are looking at $(1-p)^{n-1}$, whereas when we consider $k=0$ we need to obtain the same expression which is given by $(1-p)^{n-k-1}$ if it was $(1-p)^{n-k+1}$ then we would obtain $(1-p)^{n+1}$. The argument holds for the rest of the terms in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit too many question, this is discouraged on MSE. Nevertheless:

1. This is CDF, i.e. the expression is $P( Y \leq x)$, which, by the way, doesn't exist in closed form (partial sum of rows of Pascal's triangle),
2. You take the derivative of the product of two functions of $p: p^k$ and $(1-p)^{n-k}$
3. Do the algebra.
4. You may try logging the expression, due to $\log x +\log y = \log (xy)$, and differentiating the sum is easier than the product.

Comment: 2. Perhaps I meant form line 2 to 3, after the derivative had already been taken. (n choose k)*k = (n choose k-1)*(n-k+1). How?? I am trying to understand the algebra, I just don't know what's happening. k (n!/(k!(n-k)!) = (n-k+1) (n!/((k-1)!(n-k+1)!)) ? But how?

Comment: keep in mind $\binom{n}{k}(n-k) = n \binom{n-1}{k}$

Comment: $$\begin{align}\binom{n}{k}&=\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\cdots\times(n-(k-1))}{1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times (k-1)\times k}\\k\binom{n}{k}&=\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\cdots\times(n-k+1)}{1 \times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times (k-1)\times k}\times k\\&= \frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\cdots\times(n-k+2)}{1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times (k-1)}\times (n-k+1)\\&= \binom{n}{k-1}(n-k+1).\end{align}$$